# How to retrieve few records initially from the service and then rest of all

Tags: angular

Could you please let me know how to retrieve first few records from the service and then the rest of all records.
I have a service with datatable where it loads all records into the datatable. Now the service taking long time to retrieve all the records.So for that i need few records retrieved first and then the remaining records.

Below is my code which calls the service

```
this.http.post(serviceURL,request, { headers: headers})
.map((res: Response) => { res.json(); }).catch(this.handleError);
```

Let me know how to implement it using Observables. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's depends of web service (backend) that provide the data, you can put a param in the api with the count of elements that you want and other params with startIndex.